# Type of class which implements multiple interfaces

Tags: java, interface

I'm currently trying to write some classes and I come accross the following problem:

I'm trying to write a class that implements some functionality from two interfaces

```
interface IA {
 public void doSomething();
}

interface IB {
 public void doSomethingToo();
}
```

And I have two classes implementing those interfaces:

```
class FooA implements IA, IB{

}

class FooB implements IA, IB{

}
```

Is there I way I can do this:

```
public <type> thisClassImGonnaUse = returnEitherFooAOrFooB();
thisClassImGonnaUse.doSomething();
thisClassImGonnaUse.doSomethingToo();
```

Comment: so `thisClassImGonnaUse` should have both methods available. I don't see why this will not work. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Well, yeah kinda. What type does `thisClassImGonnaUse` have :)

Comment: ok, think i got it. The type needs to be an interface, and 2 interfaces cannot be specified as <type>.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do a new interface

```
public interface IAandB extends IA, IB
```

and make FooA and FooB implement it instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can create an abstract base class or another interface that extends both IA and IB

```
abstract class Base implements IA, IB{}
```

and

```
class FooA extends Base implements IA, IB{...}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. You've chosen to use an abstract class, what would be the difference from using an interface? It's probably semantic, but I can't really figure out what would be preferable.

Comment: In this case, nothing really! In your case, since you don't have a base class, using abstract class is also a possibility and just wanted to throw it out there. I was going to say `an abstract base class or another interface` and give examples for both but I saw other answers with examples for interface method so I did not provide an example for that.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be exactly what you want, but you could make a 3rd interface that extends both of them:

```
interface IAandB extends A, B {}
```

Then `FooA` and `FooB` would implement `IAandB` instead of `IA` and `IB` directly:

```
class FooA implements IAandB{}
class FooB implements IAandB{}
```

Then you can declare `thisClassImGonnaUse` to be of type `IAandB`:

```
public IAandB thisClassImGonnaUse = returnEitherFooAorFooB();
thisClassImGonnaUse.doSomething();
thisClassImGonnaUse.doSomethingToo();
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is the possibility that a class implementes `IA` *and* `IB`, and this fact makes conceptually sense for the problem domain you're working in, the just have a `IAB` like this

```
interface IAB extends IA, IB { /* nothing */ }
```

Do determine *if* it makes sense in your case might be as simple as asking yourself *what would be a good name for IAB?* If you can come up with a satisfactory answer to this, you can just add that interface. If *not*, then the right place for your two

```
thisClassImGonnaUse.doSomething();
thisClassImGonnaUse.doSomethingToo();
```

lines would be a method of `FooA` or `FooB` (or an base class of these two). This way you don't have to make casts or guesses about the nature of the classes that implement your interfaces (which might become invalid or troublesome to handle later).

Comment: Allright, yeah I was also thinking for that. I have one problem though, one of the interfaces (lets say `IA`) is from a different library.